# how to get data with $gte $lte

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get some datas by mongoose.

```
   let datas =
    await Data.find({
    '$and': [
      { test_id: testId },
      { createdAt: { $gte: moment(req.query.from).startOf('day') } },
      { createdAt: { $lte: moment(req.query.to).endOf('day') } }
    ],
  });
```

This is works. But, I try to change aggregate, I can't get any data.
How should I get same result?

```
  const datas = await Data.aggregate([
{
  '$match': {
    '$and': [
      { test_id: testId },
      { createdAt: { $gte: moment(req.query.from).startOf('day') } },
      { createdAt: { $lte: moment(req.query.to).endOf('day') } }
    ],
  }
}]);
```

My definition is like this.

```
 const Data = new Schema({
  test_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  item: {
    agent_id: { type: String, ref: 'Company' },
    product_no: { type: String, required: true },
    user_id: { type: String, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },1 },
    standard_price: { type: Number},
    designation: { type: String },
    category: { type: String },
    weight: { type: Number },
    materials: { type: String },
    remarks: { type: String },
    note: { type: String },
    location: String,
    image: String
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
```

And when I change the condition only { test_id: testId },
I can get the data. I doubt of term conditions in the aggregate.
But I don't know how to resolve it.

mongoose version is "5.11.15".

"mongoose": "5.11.15",

Comment: Do you get anything when you try to run `{ test_id: testId }` only?

Comment: Your aggregate looks correct. Can you validate that all the variables in the query are defined?

Comment: Konrad Linkowski
Yes, I only add { test_id: testId } except for Term Conditions.

Comment: Dimi Vi: Yes, I can show you definition.

Comment: Dimi Vi: I adds definition. Please check about it.

Comment: I could resolve by myself!
it has to use new Date('2013-07-29T20:15:09.000Z')....

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1599